# spawn a new xterm window

Tags: windows, unix, ssh, xterm

When I am using Bitvise Tunnelier and I spawn a new xterm window connecting to our sun station everything works nicely. We have visual slick edit installed on the sun station and I have been instructed to open it using the command vs&. When I do this I get the following:

```
fbm240-1:/home/users/ajahn 1 % vs&
[1] 4716
fbm240-1:/home/users/ajahn 2 % Visual SlickEdit: Can't open connection to X. DIS
PLAY='<Default Display>'
```

I would rather not go jumping through hoops ftping my material back and forth to the server.
Advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need an Xwindows server on your Windows box in order to run graphical Unix apps remotely on the Sun server and have it display on your Windows box.  I don't think Tunnelier supports Xwindows tunneling.  Take a look at Xming, an Xwindows server for Windows that comes with Putty, an ssh client:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming

**edit:** Glad to see this worked for you.  Here's some more explanation on what's happening.  X-Windows, the Unix graphical environment is client-server based.  IE: it's able to display individual graphical windows on remote systems without full-screen software like VNC or remote desktop.  A graphical program in Unix is called the X-Windows client, and the thing that actually does the displaying is called an X-Windows server.

Now, Bitvise Tunnelier is just an ssh client.  IE: it only deals with command-line terminal connections.  However, the ssh protocol is actually able to tunnel X-Windows over ssh, but you need two things: 1) an X-Windows server running on your desktop (to actually display the app), and 2) an ssh client that supports X-Windows tunneling.  Enter Xming, a lightweight X server for windows, and Putty, the ssh client.

So, you were fine ssh-ing in to your Sun box, and typing terminal commands, but Visual SlickEdit is an X-Windows client app.  To run that, you needed an X-Windows server.  When an X-Windows server is available, it sets the DISPLAY variable on the terminal to tell graphical apps where to display stuff.

One more note:  Some of the answers below recommended that you set the DISPLAY variable to the hostname of your Sun box.  That might have worked, but it would have displayed the VS windows on the Sun's screen, not your Windows box.

Comment: See, when he said "spawn a new xterm window", I failed to guess that he didn't actually mean xterm.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that Tunnelier doesn't contain an X server so I assumed that he was confused about that detail.

Answer (score 0):

What is your DISPLAY environment variable in the shell where you run vs? Is it really "<Default Display>"? If yes, try setting it up to ":0" or "*yourhostname*:0" and then running vs again (you might need to use `xhost +` on your host).

That's only a fraction of the clarifications needed to help you with this.

Comment: turns out I needed an Xming??? server running in order to open additional windows. Now it seems to work though I dont' understand exactly what is going on.

Comment: Unfortunately, I took your "spawn a new xterm" literally and didn't guess that in reality you didn't have an X server on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

On the system with the display (the one you start the tunneler on):

xhost +fbm240-1

Replace fbm240-1 with the name of the system if that's not it. I guessed.

You also need to make sure your DISPLAY is set properly; if you're using ssh tunneling then it should be already (if openssh, use -Y; if putty then select "Enable X11 forwarding" under Connection->SSH->X11; if other, then read the docs). Most likely if you have X tunneling setup properly then you won't have to mess around with xhost at all.